# What happens to a user request when a Mongrel thread locks up & gets restarted by monit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monitoring, mongrel

I cannot find an answer to this anywhere I've looked so hoping someone can help.

We run a pack of 30 mongrel servers & have just started to use monit to identify locked threads and restart them.

My question is, what happens to the users request, which was being handled by the locked thread when this happens - especially, what do they see in their browser?

I assume they get some sort of error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If Mongrel is forcibly restarted, the user gets a "Connection was reset by peer" message, usually, or in some cases, just a blank screen. If you want to test it, you can simulate it with an action that just calls while(1) {}, and then kill the mongrel running it.